# Escape # symbol in serialized string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, string

I have a serialized string which I am sending to server something like below:

```
counter=1&Id=4&type=2332&amount=3232&gstIncluded=3232&paymentMethod=2&notes=2332#fdsf&docId=0&ref=3232&isEdit=true
```

The problem which I am facing here is that there is "#" symbol in notes added by user. This results in breaking of the query string and I don't receive data after # in controller. Even docId, ref and isEdit are skip.

Can anyone please tell the better solution for this.

I have tried html escape the notes field but it don't escapes #.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` is a character that you'd need to encode when it's in a URI (Uniform Resource Identifier), because it's normally used to show which ID has been selected/directed to.

You may see a `#` at the end of the URI in the address bar, and it may be followed by the ID of an element on the page - an example is the Lodash docs ([`_.uniqBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#uniqBy) for example. You can use the inbuilt `encodeURIComponent` function to encode it. Encoded, it looks like `%23`:

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent("#"));
```

You can also encode the full URI in this way:

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent("counter=1&Id=4&type=2332&amount=3232&gstIncluded=3232&paymentMethod=2&notes=2332#fdsf&docId=0&ref=3232&isEdit=true"));
```

Comment: You shouldn't call `encodeURIComponent` on the full URL. It will encode the `=` and `&` characters, so they won't perform their normal delimiting action. You need to encode each name and value separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `encodeURIComponent` on notes value (and only on this specific value, otherwise you won't be able to parse other params) - it will escape the hashtag.
See docs on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let url = "counter=1&Id=4&type=2332&amount=3232&gstIncluded=3232&paymentMethod=2&notes=2332#fdsf&docId=0&ref=3232&isEdit=true";
url.replace("#","%23");
```

Then send it to the server will take the ascii value of reserve character

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` is a better way to do this. `#` might not be the only character that needs to be escaped.

Comment: @Barmar agreed totally